# Input field from Knockout Template not accepting the input mask

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-inputmask

I have a field for VAT registration number.
I assign it a mask from the JQuery.InputMask library;

$("input.vatreg").inputmask("999-9999-99");

In Knockout I use the following edit template;

```
<script id="editTmpl" type="text/html">
    <tr>
        <td><input data-bind="value: Name, hasFocus: addNew" /></td>
        <td><input data-bind="value: VatRegistrationNumber" class="vatreg" /></td>
        <td>
            <button data-bind="click: $root.acceptItemEdit" style="margin-right:10px;">Accept and Save</button>
            <button data-bind="click: $root.cancelItemEdit">Cancel</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

As you can see, this uses the vatreg class and my expectation was that the mask would be enabled for this field, but it isn't.
How do I fix this?

Comment: Where are you executing "$("input.vatreg").inputmask("999-9999-99");"? It's possible that it's trying to add the mask before the elements exist in the dom.

Comment: Yes I think this is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

think you may need a custom binding. I made one. run the snippet below.  the top input box is the custom binding.  the span below is the value of the observable. and the last input box is to test updating the observable and making sure the input mask is updated.

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.inputmask = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    $(element).inputmask("999-9999-99", {
      "oncomplete": function() {
        valueAccessor()($(element).val());
      }
    });

    //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
    ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function() {
      $(element).inputmask("destroy");
    });

  },
  //update the control when the view model changes
  update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
    var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
    $(element).val(valueAccessor()());
  }
};



function model() {
  var self = this;
  this.VatRegistrationNumber = ko.observable('888-8888-88');

}

var mymodel = new model();

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(mymodel);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask/3.x/dist/jquery.inputmask.bundle.js"></script>

<p>
input mask:
<input data-bind="inputmask: VatRegistrationNumber" class="vatreg" />
</p>
</br>
<p>
  input mask value: <span data-bind="text: VatRegistrationNumber"></span>
</p>

<br>
update the value <input data-bind="value: VatRegistrationNumber" class="vatreg" />
```

Comment: Yes that worked. Although the following line for the update does not appear to be needed; var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
I called my handler inputmaskvatreg just to be clear what it is for.